# Application tried to present a nil modal view controller but VC is not nil

Tags: uiviewcontroller, ios8, xcode6

I have this code in a separate method called CommonMethods:

```
- (void) displayAlert: (NSString *)alertTitle andData: (NSString *) alertMessage andTag: (int) tag andVC: (UIViewController *) vc  {

UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController
                                      alertControllerWithTitle:alertTitle
                                      message:alertMessage
                                      preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction
                               actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", @"Cancel action")
                               style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                               handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                               {
                                   NSLog(@"Cancel action");
                               }];

UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction
                           actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"OK action")
                           style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                           handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                           {
                               NSLog(@"OK action");
                           }];

[alertController addAction:cancelAction];
[alertController addAction:okAction];

[vc presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

}

When I call this method from any view controller, using this code:

```
            CommonMethods *cm = [CommonMethods new];
        [cm displayAlert:NSLocalizedString(@"Client not selected.",nil)
                 andData:NSLocalizedString(@"You must select a client to create the appointment",nil)
                  andTag:2
                   andVC:self];
```

I always get the above error, even tho' *vc* is not nil.

What is causing this, and how do I fix it?

Comment: If the error is happening in the code you posted then the error message suggests that the problem would be with `alertController` rather than `vc`.

Comment: Yes, you are right!  Now, how do I fix it?  I took some code from Apples sample (https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/index.html), and it also crashed. (no matter how I allocate it, it's still *nil*)

Comment: This **is** iOS 8.x, right?

Comment: yes... the problem is that no matter how I try to instantiate alertController, it's still *nil*...

Comment: Understood...I don't see anything obvious.  Is it nil immediately on return from `alertControllerWithTitle:` (as opposed to being overwritten between there and the "present")?

Comment: I found the problem -- the *deployment target* was set to 7.1... in 8.x it works like it should... now, I just have to figure out if I want to support 7.1 or not.  Please rewrite your comment (the last one) as the answer so I can give you the points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the iOS 8.x comment led to a solution, though why Xcode didn't flag the use of a SDK 8 class for iOS 7 deployment is anyone's guess.